# Mongo Look up error: FieldPath field names may not start with ‘$’

Tags: mongodb

```
 $lookup: {
  from: 'images',
  localField: 'fav_icon.$id',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'test'
}
```

I am trying to perform lookup operation in mongo compass. It throws FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.

Comment: The error is clear. Your localField: `'fav_icon.$id'` contains `$`.

Comment: What is your document look like?